# How can we unit test both our Python code and Javascript code from App Engine deploys?

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, nosetests

We currently run and deploy on app engine, but use GitHub as version control. What is the best way to run a series of tests every time we push to GitHub, both client-side Javascript tests, using something like PhantomJS as well as something like NoseTests for Python?
The reason being that client side code is in Javascript while the server side code is in Python.
And since we have existing credits, we'd prefer not to go for a 3rd part hosted solution. App Engine also provides a pipeline for just node tests, but this doesn't cover the Javascript unit tests.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe github commit webhooks are what you are looking for. I have not personally set them up, but at my day job, we have it automatically run a handful of things including builds + tests.

https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Google Scrip](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/load_test) to accurately test the backend loads. Unfortunately I don't know of anything from JS.

> In the documentation for App Engine and in presentations we've given at Google I/O we have mentioned that you should ramp up slowly when load testing an application on App Engine. Ramping up too quickly won't give an accurate picture of how App Engine scales; you have to accomodate our load balancing code which determines how many instances of your application to spin up by watching how much traffic is directed to your application. That monitoring and adjustment takes time, therefore the need for not ramping up too quickly.
>
> I've looked at various load testing tools and in the end wrote my own short script in Python which I use as a base for all my load testing. This isn't to say that what I have here is better for load testing than the available packages, please look at them and judge them against your own criteria. I'm most comfortable with Python and a skeleton script that can be tweaked for each test scenario is optimal for me.

Comment: Load testing is interesting, but this isn't what OP asked about.